# Sorting a list containing objects of a class in python

Tags: python, class, sorting, object

I have the following code, where I use a class `stat` to keep my data. Objects of type `stat` are inserted in a list. However, when I try to call the method `printStats`, I get the error, `AttributeError: stat instance has no attribute 'printStats'`. Secondly I want to know how can I sort the list containing objects of `stat`. My sorting should be based on the `blocks` field of `stat`.

```
fi = open( 'txt/stats.txt', 'r' )
fo = open( 'compile/stats.txt', 'w' )
list = []

class stat():
    def __init__(self, fname, blocks, backEdges):
        self.fname = fname
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.backEdges = backEdges
    def printStats(self):
        print self.fname + str(self.blocks) + str(self.backEdges)

while True:
    line_str = fi.readline()
    if line_str == '':
        break

    str = line_str.split()
    list.append( stat(str[0], int(str[1]), int(str[2])) )

for item in list:
    item.printStats() # <-- problem calling this
```

Comment: It is also good practice to inherit from `object`.  e.g. `class stat(object):`

Comment: Also, instead of your `while True` loop, you could just do `for line_str in fi:` since file objects support iteration.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: You should also check your indentation.  Even though it may look right in your editor, you may have mixed tabs and spaces or something silly like that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the sorting is concerned, you definitely *can* use the `key` function:

```
import operator
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.blocks)
lst.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('blocks') ) #alternative without lambda.
```

However, if you want to be able to compare `stats` objects in a non-sorting context, you can override `__eq__`,`__gt__`,`__lt__` (and to make your life easier, you can use the [functools.total_ordering](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator to define most of the comparisons for you):

```
import functools
@functools.total_ordering
class stats(object): #inherit from object.  It's a good idea
    def __init__(self, fname, blocks, backEdges):
        self.fname = fname
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.backEdges = backEdges
    def printStats(self):
        print self.fname + str(self.blocks) + str(self.backEdges)
    def __eq__(self,other):
         return self.blocks == other.blocks
    def __lt__(self,other):
         return self.blocks < other.blocks
```

with `stats` defined this way, sorting should again be as simple as:

```
lst.sort()  #or if you want a new list:  new_lst = sorted(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list.sort(key= lambda x:x.blocks)
```

example:

```
>>> a=stat('foo',20,30)
>>> a.printStats()
foo2030
>>> b=stat('foo',15,25)
>>> c=stat('foo',22,23)
>>> lis=[a,b,c]
>>> lis.sort(key= lambda x:x.blocks)
>>> '  '.join(str(x.blocks) for x in lis)   #sorted
'15  20  22'
```

Comment: But why am I getting AttributeError: stat instance has no attribute 'printStats' error here

Answer (score 0):

The function `printStats` is not actually part of your `stat` class because it uses tabbed indentation while the rest of the class uses space indentation. Try `print dir(stat)` and you'll see that `printStats` is absent. To fix this, change the tabbing style so that it is consistent throughout the class.

You should also look at this line:

```
str = line_str.split()
```

You are overwriting the built-in type `str` with your own list. As a result, you can no longer use `str` to convert things into strings. When you do successfully call `printStats`, it will give you a `TypeError`.  Change the name of your `str` variable to something else.

Comment: While you're right, (OP *is* shadowing `str` and that should cause an exception at some point in this code) I don't see how this would cause the `AttributeError` that the OP described ...

Comment: Yep, I jumped the gun a little bit and posted the fix that made it work on _my_ machine. I guess the OP has a different environment than me, since I got a different error.

Comment: Yeah.  My guess is that it's a mixing tabs and spaces issue or the code that we see above isn't actually the OP's code.

Comment: Interesting observation, @mgilson. When I copy OP's code from the edit window, I get `AttributeError`, but when I copy it from the question, I get `TypeError`. It does look like it has something to do with indentation.

Comment: SO probably magically converts tabs to spaces for displaying in the question.

Comment: See this post on meta ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17715/make-wmd-convert-tabs-to-spaces ).  I don't know what `WMD` actually is, but I'm guessing it is the code responsible for displaying the output.